# How to I know which Java variable/path is the one I need, I updated my ubuntu, now hadoop and hives won't work

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop, jvm, java-home

Background first, I installed hadoop on ubuntu 14, but now I updated it to 16, and the java was updated too, from 1.7 to 1.8. But now my hadoop won't work and I'm trying install Hives. I updated my bashrc and source it, but hadoop still won't work.

This is my current java home:

```
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:~$
```

But when I tried to open my usr/lib/jvm folder, there are two java, which one should I use for my java path for hadoop and hives? The java 1.8 or java-8? I mean to edit the bashrc for hadoop and hives?

```
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls
default-java  java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:/usr/lib/jvm$
```

I also tried this command, I believe it is to find your default java path, it gave me this:

```
dachen@dachen-VirtualBox:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for dachen: 
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
dachen@dachen-Virtual
```

Comment: Most probably that `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` is a symbolic link to `java-8-openjdk-amd64`. Use `ls -al` to see what is real and what is a link. For your Hadoop problem, please define "won't work" by giving more details.

Comment: sir are you good with hadoop or hive, if so can you start with a chat with me so I can give you update?